# Benefits of using an invite code in Ingress

Tags: ingress

I have a lot of invite codes saved up, and I was wondering, if I gave an invite code to someone, would they get anything out of using it, like extra items or a bonus?  For me, it could help towards one of the badges (potentially useful for leveling up), but I was wondering if the recipient gets anything out of it, especially as an invite code is certainly not needed for joining.

Comment: The Recruiter badge. Accepted invites count as soon as the invitee reaches Level 3.

Comment: It would also not be answer to the question, which is about what the *recipient* gets out of being recruited vs. joining independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: Apparently nothing.

The recruiter obviously gets something (a point on the Recruiter badge, as soon as the recipient reaches Level 3), but that's not the point of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Years ago Ingress was invite-only, you needed a code to join. Even then it gave no new items or anything, and AFAIK it still does not.

Invites are left in the game, possibly because that's cheaper and easier than removing them. And they can still be useful, you talk about the game with your mate and they're interested, you can send them an invite and the email is a reminder of the talk and the game's name.

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question …

Comment: … also, they're still useful in-game. For the recruiter.